# Distributed Transaction ( XA ) using atomikos with mySql and Oracle not working

Tags: transactions, spring-transactions, xa, atomikos

Am trying to test distributed / XA transactions .
Am using mySql , Oracle , Atomikos and spring
No application server is being used - so please dont point me to app server solutions.

In a Transaction - first am trying to update Oracle table
Then in same transaction am tryng to insert into MySql
I am ensuring that the insert fails due to a Unique constraint on the table.
Ideally since mysql was unsuccessful - Oracle update should also rollback - but that does not seem to be happening - Oracle table update is happening based on sysdate .
So here is the complete code:
**spring config file:**

```
<bean id="userTransactionService" class="com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="shutdownForce">
    <constructor-arg>
        <props>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.service">
                com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.tm_unique_name">myname</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_name">myLogName</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir">xyz/atomikos</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.checkpoint_interval">100</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.console_file_count">2</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout">300000</prop>
            <prop key="com.atomikos.icatch.max_actives">128</prop>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>  
</bean>

<bean id="AtomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager"
    init-method="init" destroy-method="close" depends-on="userTransactionService">
    <property name="startupTransactionService" value="false" />
    <property name="forceShutdown" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="AtomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp"
    depends-on="userTransactionService">
    <property name="transactionTimeout" value="300" />
</bean>

<bean id="jtaTxManager"
    class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager"
    depends-on="userTransactionService">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="AtomikosTransactionManager" />
    <property name="userTransaction" ref="AtomikosUserTransaction" />
</bean>

<bean id="myTxTest" class="com.runner.MyTxTester">      
    <property name="oraUpdater" ref="myOraUpdater" />
    <property name="mySqlInserter" ref="mySqlInserter" />
    <property name="txManager" ref="jtaTxManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="mySqlInserter" class="com.xyz.dao.MySqlInserter">
    <property name="sql"
        value="insert into person (name,country) values ('abc','USA');" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="MySqldataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="myOraUpdater" class="com.xyz.dao.OraUpdater">
    <property name="sql"
        value="UPDATE PurchaseOrders SET LAST_UPDATE=SYSDATE" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="OraDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="OraDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe" />
    <property name="username" value="TEST1" />
    <property name="password" value="TEST11" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource" />        
</bean>

<bean id="MySqldataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test2" />
    <property name="username" value="test2" />
    <property name="password" value="test2" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />       
</bean>
```

Here is how I kickstart everything:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("instance-spring.xml");
        MyTxTester tester = (MyTxTester) context.getBean("myTxTest");
        tester.wrapperCall();

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The class that invokes things:

```
public class MyTxTester {
private final SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator = new SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator();
private PlatformTransactionManager txManager;
private DBUpdater<SqlParameterSource> oraUpdater;
private DBUpdater<SqlParameterSource> mySqlInserter;

public void wrapperCall(){      
    TransactionTemplate txTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(txManager);
    txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Object>() {
        public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
            try {
                //do oracle update
                doOraUpdate();
                //do mysql insert   
                doMySqlInsert();
            } catch (Exception sqle) {
                throw exceptionTranslator.translate("SQLException ","abc", new SQLException());
            }   
            return null;
        }
    });
}

public void doOraUpdate(){
    System.out.println(" first going for Oracle update ");
    getOraUpdater().update();
}

public void doMySqlInsert(){
    System.out.println(" second going for mySql insert ");
    getMySqlInserter().insert();
}
```

The Dao class -

```
public class OraUpdater<E extends SqlParameterSource>  {

/** The data source. */
private DataSource dataSource;

/** The jdbc template. */
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

/** The sql. */
private String sql;

public Object update()  {
    SqlParameterSource paramSource = null;
    getJdbcTemplate().update(getSql(), paramSource);
    return null;
}
```

The MySqlDao:

```
public class MySqlInserter<E extends SqlParameterSource>  {

/** The data source. */
private DataSource dataSource;

/** The jdbc template. */
private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

/** The sql. */
private String sql;

public Object insert()  {
    SqlParameterSource paramSource = null;
    getJdbcTemplate().update(getSql(), paramSource);
    return null;
}
```

So not sure what I am missing to ensure atomicity?

Comment: @mdeinum if could you please help here

Answer (score 0):

The dbcp.BasicDatasource does not support XA. Instead the dbcp.BasicManagedDatasource needs to be used. In addition make sure that also XADataSource properties are set.